# Handling concurrency/Multiple client connections in FastAPI

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, fastapi

I am just getting started with FastAPI and mongodb, and I am a bit lost about how concurrency is handled in FastAPI?

Do I need initiate/start a new Thread/task for each new request or is it handled automatically?

**take this code for example :**

```
@router.get("/UserProfile",tags=['Dashboard'], dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearer())])
def get_user_profile(user: str, Authorization: str | None = Header(default=None)):
    token = Authorization.replace("Bearer ", "")
    decoded = jwt.decode(token, options={"verify_signature": False})
    user_id = decoded['user_id']
    if db.Admin.count_documents({'username':  user_id}):
        data = db.Users.find_one({'username': user}, {
                                 "_id": 0, "phone": 1, "email": 1, "username": 1, "state": 1, "dob": 1, "add": 1})
        return {"message": data}
    else:
        return {"message": "Un-Authorized!"}
```

This code is accepting a request from client side , and then checking the jwt is valid or not , if its valid then checks if the requesting user matches with a user in admin database , if user matches then get a user's profile data from "users" database and return this data.

This code works fine for what I intend to do , but my question is what will happen if there are let's say a 1000 requests to the same `/UserData` end point? if we consider the same code as above then, will all 1000 requests be handled simultaneously ? or will if be handled one after another ?

I am trying to understand how "multiple requests at once" is handled in fastapi

Comment: you should use motor package for mongodb and write code async.

Answer (score 0):

As written, your code will handle one request at a time. To handle multiple requests at once, you can use multiprocessing.

FastAPI doesn't handle requests directly, the web server (eg. uvicorn) does. If you run FastAPI with uvicorn, you can use Gunicorn do define a number of uvicorn workers to handle multiple requests at once like so (replacing main by your file name and app with your web application's name):

```
gunicorn main:app --workers 4 --worker-class
```

See this page for more info on how to install and configure Gunicorn with Uvicorn and FastAPI:
[Server Workers - Gunicorn with Uvicorn](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/)